# Blazor Server Custom ValidationAttribute using Database

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I'm trying to implement a custom validation attribute for unique records. For that I need to check the database, so I can notify user that given data already exists.

For that I need to access database inside of IsValid method of my Custom validation attribue:

```
public class CustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //This is always null
            var context = (DataContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(DataContext));
            
        }
    }
```

I alredy tried to implement custom DataAnotation with DI acording to this post:
[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67096287/using-a-database-with-custom-validators?msclkid=d43fb9a3b1cc11ec82c272cdfa4ffbdf)

but it does not work. Maybe due to .net6 changes? I get error that EditContext cannot by changed dynamicaly.

Can some point me in the rigth direction please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection in ValidationAttributes should be available with .net7.0-preview1: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/39445